# How to get the statistics of a winform app usage

Tags: c#, winforms

Say I created a `winform` app and distributed to anonymous users, and I want to have a way to get the statistics of user opens the app, one way I can think of is opening a webpage (lightweight) on app startup then analyzing how many times the webpage is opened.

Any other ways to get the statistics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways.

The initial idea of having your application "phone home" to count its usage isn't that bad, but it does not have to be an entire web page.
You could just post some data to a webservice.

If it can't connect to your web service, you could store the information locally and send it next time the app starts with a valid web connection.

If you do this asynchronously, it should be hardly noticeable when you start the app.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the existing tools out there and implement them in your application for statistical usage and analytics for example as mentioned before: EQATEC.

you also have Preemptive analytics: http://www.preemptive.com/products/runtime-intelligence/overview
This is a most common used tool especially in the whole ALM lifecycle process and how applications and companies progress onwards with minimal effort story.

you also need to know exactly what kind of statistics are you monitoring here? number of times your app is run on a particular version of the software? particular screens being used within your app? memory/CPU usage? etc...

you also have trackerbird:
http://www.trackerbird.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own tracking service, which you can consume every time when application starts. Alternative way you can use any third party application/service which provides this kind of functionality. [Telerik eqatec analytics](http://www.telerik.com/analytics) could be one of its kind.